# Is there a forcing which only collapses cardinals when squared?

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

Call a forcing notion $\mathbb{P}$ *briefly tame* if $\mathbb{P}$ preserves cardinals but $\mathbb{P}^2$ does not. I vaguely recall seeing an argument that such things can't exist, but I can't reconstruct it at the moment. My question is whether my recollection is just wrong:

> Can briefly tame forcings exist in $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

Note that it's certainly the case that the square of a forcing notion can be much nastier than the original forcing itself. For example, [there is a proper forcing whose square is non-proper](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/853059/28111) - indeed, that forcing preserves $\omega_1$ but its square does not! Of course, it doesn't count since it does collapse $\omega_2$, but it is worryingly close to an example.

Comment: I might miss something, but doesn't Miha's answer for you link work? Given a Suslin tree, let $\mathbb{P}$ be the lottery sum of specializing and shooting a branch through the tree?

Comment: @tzoorp Oh yes, I missed Miha's answer there entirely! If you add that as an answer here I'll upvote and accept it.

Comment: @tzoorp I've added an answer to move this off the unanswered queue, but if you add your own I'll delete mine and accept and upvote yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is an expansion of tzoorp's comment above, which observed that an existing answer to the question linked in the OP - due to Miha Habic - actually answers this one as well. I've made this answer CW to avoid reputation gain, and will delete it if either tzoorp or Miha add an answer of their own.*

---

There is a forcing $\mathbb{P}$ with the following property: $\mathbb{P}$ does not collapse cardinals, but $\mathbb{P}^2$ *sometimes* collapses cardinals.

Specifically, working over a ground model with a Suslin tree $T$, let $\mathbb{P}_{0,T}$ be the forcing which specializes $T$ and let $\mathbb{P}_{1,T}$ be the forcing shooting a branch through $T$. These forcings are each c.c.c., hence do not collapse cardinals. However, their product does collapse $\omega_1$. Consequently, if we let $\mathbb{P}$ be their lottery sum, then $\mathbb{P}$ itself is c.c.c. but some $\mathbb{P}^2$ generics - namely, those whose left coordinate shoots a branch and whose right coordinate specializes, or vice versa - collapse $\omega_1$.

(And if we want we can make everything nicely definable by working over a ground model of $\mathsf{ZFC+V=L}$ and taking $T$ to be the $L$-least Suslin tree.)

---

This leaves open the strong form of the question: whether there is consistently a forcing which never collapses cardinals but whose square always collapses cardinals. The answer to that [turns out to be yes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/371037/good-forcings-with-bad-squares).